# Will these two SQL statements always return the same data in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking to remove the NVL function in a query as the query runs much faster without it. I'm sure something is going on in my execution plan that could be better but this appears to be potentially better sql that produces the same results. The larger query is more complex but here is basically how I'm looking to update the where clause. Will this be a good replacement? If not, why not and what would be better?

Current SQL (With NVL):

```
SELECT  *
FROM oe_order_lines_all ol  
WHERE  NVL(OL.LINK_TO_LINE_ID, OL.LINE_ID) = OL.LINE_ID
```

Replacement SQL:

```
SELECT  *
FROM oe_order_lines_all ol
WHERE (OL.LINK_TO_LINE_ID IS NULL OR OL.LINK_TO_LINE_ID = OL.LINE_ID)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, these two queries are functionally equivalent, provided OL.LINE_ID is itself never NULL, which is *probably* a good assumption...

Break it down like this to prove it:

```
SELECT  *
FROM oe_order_lines_all ol  
WHERE  NVL(OL.LINK_TO_LINE_ID, OL.LINE_ID) = OL.LINE_ID
```

is the same as

```
SELECT  *
FROM oe_order_lines_all ol  
WHERE  OL.LINK_TO_LINE_ID = OL.LINE_ID
OR     OL.LINK_TO_LINE_ID IS NULL AND OL.LINE_ID  = OL.LINE_ID
```

but since OL.LINE_ID = OL.LINE_ID when OL.LINE_ID is not NULL, that simplifies to your second query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM oe_order_lines_all ol  
WHERE  OL.LINK_TO_LINE_ID = OL.LINE_ID
OR     OL.LINK_TO_LINE_ID IS NULL
```

of course, if OL.LINE_ID is NULL when OL.LINK_TO_LINE_ID IS NULL, then OL.LINE_ID is not equal to OL.LINE_ID, and you could have different results.

Answer (score 1):

The not-an-answer answer: do an `EXPLAIN PLAN` on both.

The answer answer: yes, they are equivalent.  If `link_to_line_id` is null, then you compare `line_id` to itself, which is always true.

However, do not try to extend the pattern much further than that.  It works in this specific case because it's being used to filter results *within* a table.  If you were to use it as a join criteria with columns from different tables, it will fail miserably.

Comment: When you say "try not to extend the pattern much further", are you saying that this really isn't a replacement for NVL, it just works logically in this case?

Comment: @TonyL. - Exactly!  Consider what would happen if `link_to_line_id` and `line_id` are on different tables and you used the replacement logic to join the tables together.  (Hint: what would the `link_to_line_id = NULL` records be joined to in the other table?)

Comment: EXPLAIN PLAN will tell you if the queries are equivalent, but just because they aren't equivalent with EXPLAIN PLAN doesn't mean that they will yield different results.